# How to modify Parse Server on AWS and deploy from local machine

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, parse-server

So I deployed my Parse server using the Deploy to AWS button and got everything running. My app can connect and write data fine. I would like to modify the code on the server and deploy it but I didn't create it using the EB CLI. Does anyone know how to modify this stack given the way I deployed it initially?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: I would like to modify the CloudCode

Comment: Just because you didn't create it using the EB CLI doesn't mean you can't later install it and manage your code.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, I'm not sure how to manage the code with EB CLI if I didn't create it with EB CLI. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried reading the Advanced section at the bottom of this guide? http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, I actually was following this link: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3LNEWJS45OYA9/Setting-up-Parse-Server-and-MongoDB-on-AWS-using-CloudFormation which does not have the eb labs download command in the instructions. It seemed to work, but that brings me to my next question which I will start a new question with, a 502 error when changing the contents of the cloud folder. Thanks!

Comment: Well, still, it says at the bottom. "You can manage your Parse Server using the Elastic Beanstalk console or Elastic Beanstalk CLI."

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my response.